# Update statements with a one-to-many join

Tags: mysql

So I've come across an odd situation that doesn't behave at all how I expected.

Let's say I have the following tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (somekey char(1) PRIMARY KEY, value1 int, value2 int);

INSERT INTO test VALUES 
("a", 1, 1),
("b", 2, 2),
("c", 3, 3);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2;
CREATE TABLE test2 (somekey char(1), thing int, value int);

INSERT INTO test2 VALUES 
("a", 100, 10),
("a", 200, 10),
("b", 100, 20),
("b", 200, 20),
("c", 100, 30),
("c", 200, 30);
```

And now I want to update `test` based on `test2`:

```
UPDATE 
    test AS t 
    JOIN test2 AS t2 
        ON t.somekey = t2.somekey
SET
    t.value1 = IF(t2.thing = 100, t2.value, t.value1),
    t.value2 = IF(t2.thing = 200, t2.value, t.value2);
```

This is my output:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
+---------+--------+--------+
| somekey | value1 | value2 |
+---------+--------+--------+
| a       |     10 |      1 |
| b       |     20 |      2 |
| c       |     30 |      3 |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

For some reason, `value2` isn't updated.

I've found that if I alter `test2` such that 200 is inserted before 100, the exact opposite happens.  This leads me to believe that MySQL is essentially grouping by `somekey`, and completely ignoring half the rows in `test2`.  But if I do the exact same join and just update something in `test2` based on `test`, it doesn't do the grouping and all six rows in `test2` are updated.

The simple solution is to simple join to `test2` twice, like so:

```
UPDATE 
    test AS t 
    JOIN test2 AS t100 
        ON t100.somekey = t.somekey
        AND t100.thing = 100
    JOIN test2 AS t200
        ON t200.somekey = t.somekey
        AND t200.thing = 200
SET
    t.value1 = t100.value,
    t.value2 = t200.value;
```

but I just don't feel I should have to do it this way.  What's wrong with the first update?  Why is MySQL behaving this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When updating with a JOIN, without a filter (WHERE), there will be a cartesian product. In this case, since there are 2 rows of `test2` per single row of `test`, it means that there will be two updates per `test` row.

From [the Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

Which as far as I can see means that we have no control over which of the 2 possible row values will be used during the update - MySql has chosen the `value = value` option.

Your second update query defines only a single possible value for `test.value1` and `test.value2`, thus removing the ambiguity.

Comment: Ah, thanks for finding that in the docs.  At least it seems to be intended behavior.