# Different result in mysql in windows and linux

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am migrating mysql from linux to Windows machine. I have a update query which is using a mapping table gives different result in windows and linux. 
I provided the steps to recreate the issue and the result i got.

Follow the below steps in Linux:

1. Create required table

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `buildmapping` ( 
   `ver` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `build` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `branchname` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `buildminor` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
   UNIQUE KEY `bmap` (`ver`,`build`,`branchname`,`buildminor`), 
   KEY `ak` (`ver`), 
   KEY `br` (`branchname`), 
   KEY `bi` (`build`) 
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ; 

   CREATE TABLE `s_Last7days` ( 
   `ver` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `build` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `branchname` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `buildminor` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL 
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
2. Insert required data

   ```
   Insert into buildmapping values ('1522','105','release_01','682');
   Insert into buildmapping values ('1384','105','release_01','682');    
   Insert into buildmapping values ('1090','105','release_01','682');
   Insert into s_Last7days values ('0','105','release_01','682');
   ```
3. Update fact using mapping table

   ```
   update s_Last7days b , buildmapping c 
   set b.ver=c.ver 
   where b.ver=0 
   and b.Build=c.build 
   and b.BuildMinor=c.buildminor 
   and b.branchname=c.branchname;
   ```
4. Validate the data

   ```
   select * from s_Last7days;
   ```

   ```
   +------+-------+------------+------------+
   | ver  | build | branchname | buildminor |
   +------+-------+------------+------------+
   | 1522 | 105   | release_01 | 682        |
   +------+-------+------------+------------+
   ```
5. Take the dump from Linux server:

   ```
   mysqldump -uxxxxx -pxxxxxx -hxxxxx databasename buildmapping > buildmapping_bk1128.sql
   ```
6. SSH the file to Windows server

Follow the below steps in Windows server:

1. Restore the table in Windows. (I used MySQL Workbench)
2. Create required table

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `s_Last7days` ( 
   `ver` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `build` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `branchname` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL, 
   `buildminor` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL 
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
3. Insert required data

   ```
   Insert into s_Last7days values ('0','105','release_01','682');
   ```
4. Update fact using mapping table

   ```
   update s_Last7days b , buildmapping c 
   set b.ver=c.ver 
   where b.ver=0 
   and b.Build=c.build 
   and b.BuildMinor=c.buildminor 
   and b.branchname=c.branchname;
   ```
5. Validate the data

   ```
   select * from s_Last7days;
   ```

   ```
   +------+-------+------------+------------+
   | ver  | build | branchname | buildminor |
   +------+-------+------------+------------+
   | 1090 | 105   | release_01 |  682       |
   +------+-------+------------+------------+
   ```

I want both servers to be in sync. Could someone help me on this issue?

Comment: Your `buildmapping` table has multiple rows that match the `branchname` and `buildminor`.  It looks like Windows and Linux are getting them in a different order.

Comment: If that is the case (I quickly scanned) it means you messed up on your logic

Comment: The problem is that you're *assuming* that the rows will be returned in the same order every time, which is not the case. The only way to insure the ordering of rows is to include an ORDER BY.

Comment: yes, multiple record satisfy the condition. Its an error in the mapping table. But this system was developed long back and even though duplicates are there in mapping table, current linux system is working as expected. It is not developed by me, i am just doing migration work. Any clue how to make windows server to select the same record as linux?

Comment: We've just told you. Add an ORDER BY to select TOP 1 ORDER BY ver DESC. It's never safe to assume anything, particularly when dealing with data.

Answer (score 0):

It's a characteristic of SQL that a result set specified without an `ORDER BY` clause has its rows returned in an **unpredictable** order. That's sort of like saying they're returned in a **random** order. But, the trouble is, they're usually returned in the same order as last time, **until they're not.** If this stuff were truly random, defects like this one in your database on Linux would be less likely to creep in: somebody would detect them and fix them.

The result set you're talking about in this case is.

```
select c.ver 
  from s_Last7days b , buildmapping c 
 where b.ver=0 
   and b.Build=c.build 
   and b.BuildMinor=c.buildminor 
   and b.branchname=c.branchname;
```

Notice that it returns three different values of `ver`. When you use this result set in your update, it updates the row three times, once for each value in the result set. The one that happens to come last is the one that sticks.

You have discovered that the MySQL server you're running on Windows has a different meaning of *unpredictable* than the server you're running on Linux.

**There is no way** to force your two servers to have the same meaning of **unpredictable**.  It can't be done.  You must eliminate the unpredictability from your query, or live with the unpredictability. This query grabs the largest value of `ver`.

```
select c.ver 
  from s_Last7days b , buildmapping c 
 where b.ver=0 
   and b.Build=c.build 
   and b.BuildMinor=c.buildminor 
   and b.branchname=c.branchname
 order by c.ver DESC
 limit 1
```

Your Linux database has a bug that makes it impossible to port to Windows unchanged. You've been lucky (or perhaps unlucky) that the bug has gone undiscovered until now. You must fix this bug as you port this database, or live with the consequences of the bug.

Comment: Thank you Jones,Rocket,Drew and ken. Yes, I will try to fix it in current server. That will be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your update command is using a one-to-many relationship to choose which value from buildmapping should be used into s_Last7days.ver field.
So only the first matching tuple in natural order will be used.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826811/update-statements-with-a-one-to-many-join)